# Two simple properties - improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was working through some proofs of various criteria for convergence/divergence of improper integrals. I noticed that I am using two things which were not explicitly formulated before but which seem rather obvious. So I want to ask if these are indeed true and why exactly.

In both examples $f : [a, b) \to R$ is a continuous function. So the integrals below are improper because of their upper limit ($x=b$).

$P1$: The improper integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is convergent if and only if the integral $\int_a^b (-f(x)) dx$ is convergent

$P2$: The improper integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is convergent if and only if there exist a number $\delta$ with $0 \lt \delta \lt (b-a)$, such that the improper integral $\int_{b-\delta}^b f(x) dx$ is convergent.

I think both propositions are true even though they are not mentioned explicitly so far in my book.

$P2$ is basically saying that it doesn't matter how the function behaves in the whole interval $[a,b)$, it only matters how it behaves around the point $b$ and in particular if that part of the improper integral is convergent.

**EDIT:**
The $a$ and $b$ are finite real numbers here, I am not talking about any of these being infinities (though I would be interested to know if these propositions hold true (or make sense) when $a$ or $b$ or both are infinities)

Comment: If $f$ has a continuous extension to $[a,b]$, then the integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is not improper.

Comment: @user OK, I know. Let's say we're not in this case.

Comment: Do you define $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ as $\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}\int_a^{b-\epsilon}f(x)\;dx$?

Comment: @user I didn't define it myself :) I define it as the whole world defines it. But OK... yes.

Comment: thanks. I just wanted to understand your context. Wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well for P1, since the integral is linear, we have $\int_a^b (-f(x))\, dx = -\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ so if one is convergent, the other is as well. Regarding P2, suppose that the singularity lies at $b$, i.e. that's where we have a problem. Then the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$ is by definition $$\lim_{u\to b} \int_a^u f(x)\, dx = \lim_{u\to b}\left(\int_a^{u-\delta}f(x)\, dx +\int_{u-\delta}^uf(x)\, dx\right)=\int_a^{b-\delta}f(x)\, dx + \lim_{u\to b}\int_{u-\delta}^uf(x)\, dx,$$ where the limit on the first term of the sum is convergent (since only $b$ is problematic). This shows that solving one requires solving the other and vice versa.

Comment: I cannot split so easily I was told recently. Additivity is there only if the integral is convergent, no?

Comment: Fair enough, let me rewrite my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean now. Thanks. Yeah, I was thinking along similar lines... but could not quite formalize why P1 and especially why P2 is true. So I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

P1 is true because for every "small" $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\int_a^{b-\epsilon}-f(x)\;dx=-\int_a^{b-\epsilon}f(x)\;dx$
$$

P2 is true, because any small $\delta>0$, and particularly, say $\delta=\frac{b-a}{10}$,
$$
\int_a^{b-\epsilon}f(x)\;dx=\int_{a}^{a+\delta}f(x)\;dx+\int_{a+\delta}^{b-\epsilon}f(x)\;dx\tag{1}
$$
and the first integral on the right is a Riemann integral of a continuous function on a closed interval. It follows that if the limit on the left exists as $\epsilon\to 0+$, so does that on the right, namely $\int_{a+\delta}^bf$ is convergent.

For the other direction, support $\int_{a+\delta}^bf$ is convergent. then (1) implies that $\int_{a}^bf$ is also convergent.

Comment: I am not sure my delta and your delta in P2 are the same thing. First thing you said is clear, the second is not clear to me. How does your delta relate to mine?

Comment: @peter.petrov: the difference is in the quantifiers. I actually give you something *stronger* than P2, which implies P2.

Comment: @peter.petrov: let me write it in a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

P1:  Since $\int_a^b -f(x)dx= -\int_a^b f(x)dx$, yes, if one exists then the other does.

P2:  This is true if and only if the "improperness" only occurs at b.
(I see now that you are requiring that f(x) be continuous on [a, b) so this is true.)

Comment: P2 ... Since f is defined and continuous in $[a, b)$ there's no improperness elsewhere, right?

Comment: peterpetrov: No, the function f(x)= 1/x is continuous on [-1, 0) but the integral $\int_{-1}^0 1/x dx$ is improper.

Comment: I am not saying it's not improper, I am saying there's no improperness in any other point.